# Invalid URI exception in DocumentsContract.getDocumentId (uri)

Tags: android

I am trying to get the document id of the image which I saved, I am saving the image file to the following external storage in the device.

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BeautifulFaces/kvh_20160420T225141.jpg
```

After querying querying

```
public String checkIfImageIsRotated(Uri image_uri){

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> START ");
    int rotation =0;
    String[] selection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                                        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                                        MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};

    String selectionArgs = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME +  " = ?";
    String[] args = new String[]{FOLDER_NAME};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";

    ContentResolver content = mContext.getContentResolver();
    Cursor mediaCursor = content.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                        selection ,
                                        selectionArgs,
                                        args,
                                sortOrder);

    //select of columns
    //MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
    //MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
    if (mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.getCount() !=0 ) {
        if(mediaCursor.moveToNext()){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> media cursor not null ");
            String orientation = mediaCursor.getString(4);
            String bucket_display_name = mediaCursor.getString(1);
            image_data_path = mediaCursor.getString(2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> rotation -  " + orientation + ", bucket display name - " + bucket_display_name + ", data - " + image_data_path);
        }

        mediaCursor.close();
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ">>>>> END ");
    return image_data_path;
}
```

image_data_path is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BeautifulFaces/kvh_20160420T225141.jpg
```

Now when I am trying to do DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) where uri is either the file uri mentioned at the top or image_data_path returned from the cursor, in both cases I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BeautifulFaces/kvh_20160420T225141.jpg
```

or

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BeautifulFaces/kvh_20160420T225141.jpg
```

Cannot understand why Document.getDocumentId is not able to parse the Uri.

Thanks

Comment: Well, they aren't document Uris as generated by a [DocumentsProvider](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html) - those would start with `content://` at the very least. Why were you expecting them to be document Uris?

Comment: Have you found any answers? I save images with DocumentFileclass and Uri i get from SAF UI(returns content//:com.android.externalstorage...) but i need Uri to get saved image with File class to write EXIF data in it.